# Alternative for QUnit

Tags: frameworks, qunit

What is the best alternative for QUnit unit test frameworks, also easy for understanding for an end user to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give Jasmine a try. See these references for some comparison between QUnit and Jasmine:

- [qUnit vs Jasmine - stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047419/qunit-vs-jasmine)
- [Choosing between qUnit and Jasmine - effectif.com](http://effectif.com/coffeescript/choosing-between-qunit-and-jasmine)

Easy for an end user to understand - what is that end user supposed to do? Write tests? Look at the results and decide if the product is stable enough? Unit tests are usually for the team, not for the end user (unless the end user is a technical guy/girl and can appreciate the value of unit tests)